# store and setRequest

Tags: zend-framework

I have a jobque mechanism in ZF.
The jobque simlpy stores the the function call (Class, Method and params) and later executes it as CLI daemon. The daemon works, however at places the application looks for information from the request object, and when called from the CLI these places fail, or get no info.

I would like to store the original request object together with the job and when the job is processed set the request object back as if the job was done by the originall request, somethin along the line of the following pseudo code:

```
$ser_request = serialize(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance ()->getRequest ());
-->save to db

-->retrive from db
$ZCF= new Zend_Controller_Front;
$ZCF::getInstance ()->setRequest (unserialize($ser_request))
```

The aim is to store and replay the jobs later withouth having to change the rest of the application.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works, but here's an idea. Try to implement [_*sleep*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep) and [_wakeup](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.wakeup) magic methods for the request object. Haven't tried it out, but maybe it's at least a starting solution.